# Li element with form in lower than all other Li's

Tags: html, css, list, height, styling

Js Fiddle with error: http://jsfiddle.net/mvckwoys/

The list element with the form in for some reason has a 5px height difference to all the other li's. I have tried setting the form to `display:block` and attempted to use `margin:top;` multiple times aswell as numerous other css tricks, but none seem to allow the Li to raise the 5px it is pushed down by. I have a feeling it is something to do with the form however as all the anchor tags work perfectly.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raising the `<li>` in question by 5 pixels using `position:relative;` seems to work for me:

```
<li class="form-li"><form></form></li>

.form-li {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, i never knew that the attribute 'top' could be applied negatively! helps out a bunch, thank you!